# MathJax does not finish rendering, when hiding CKEditor too soon

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mathjax

i'm using CKEditor 4.14.1, with the "Mathematical Formulas" Plugin, using Mathjax 2.7.8.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/mathjax.html

The user in our application is able to close and open the editor again, which in the end just sets the wrapping div to display:none or block.

**The problem is that if the user closes the editor before the formulas are finished rendering, and opens the editor again, the formulas won't show.**

I tried triggering the render process manually, as described here.
https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/advanced/typeset.html

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender",MathJax.Hub]);
// or
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
  ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX],
  ["PreProcess",MathJax.Hub],
  ["Reprocess",MathJax.Hub]
);
```

This didn't work though.

Here is an example. It should render the five formulas seen in the html, but is rendering none or only parts:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lh1o4ckj/

I just copied the example from the official docs (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/mathjax.html), and simulated a user hiding and showing the formula with a timeout. As this problem only shows, depending on how fast the formula is rendered, it might take a few tries.